# How to fix node-pre-gyp: Permission denied error

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

While trying to install an npm module on ubuntu server i get this error:

```
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: Permission denied

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-04-06T15_53_12_907Z-debug-0.log
```

Any ideas on how to fix

Answer (score -1):

Try using the sudo chmod 777 command for the node_modules directory and if that doesn't work try
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm
or
sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm

Comment: None does not work. :( doing sudo node-gyp rebuild -g --unsafe-perm leads to error: gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error